# How to remove my app from Now Playing Info?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, mpnowplayinginfocenter

My app start playing music and it appears in Now Playing Info, but i can't find how to clean it all: destroy the player and remove my app from Now Playing Info.

The lib that i'm using have not implemented this and i know almost nothing about ios/swift. [Here is the code](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/blob/dev/ios/RNTrackPlayer/RNTrackPlayer.swift#L153).

[This](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/issues/566) is the issue in the repo, if some mantainer see this.

And this is an ilustrative image of `Now Playing Info`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nil
```

Source from the [official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter/1615903-nowplayinginfo):

```
/// The current now playing info for the center.
/// Setting the info to nil will clear it.
open var nowPlayingInfo: [String : Any]?
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call:

```
UIApplication.shared.endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

This will remove the now playing info from your lock screen.

Comment: thanks man, I'm not able to confirm this anymore, if someone else can test this I can set this answer as correct

Comment: Sorry it's not working for me. I'm using iOS 14.